# ShieldUI ComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, shieldui

Anyone here use Shield UI ComboBox?  I just read all of the Javascript API documentation and have a specific question.

[Shield UI ComboBox Demo](https://www.shieldui.com/products/combobox)

When the user types in text, how can I have the top item from the suggestions auto-highlight?  I'm open to other suggestions.  I just have specific needs for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-highlighting the top item will mean that it is currently selected, which in turn should update the value of the text area of the ComboBox, holding the text the user has typed herself.